# Bind list property - C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Здравствуйте.
Я неудачно пытаюсь вернуть модель после отправки данных на сервер.
Модель:

```
public class UserReg
{
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string PasswordConfirm { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public Languages[] Languages { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public List<ProgLang> ProgLangList { get; set; }
}

public enum Languages
{
    English,
    Arabic,
    Japanese,
    German,
    Ukrainian,
    Russian
}
public enum Gender
{
    male,
    female
}

public class ProgLang
{
    public string lang;
    public bool Checked;
}
```

Контроллер:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        UserReg obj = new UserReg();
        obj.ProgLangList = new List<ProgLang>()
        {
            new ProgLang() { lang = "cSharp", Checked = true},
            new ProgLang() { lang = "javaScript", Checked = false},
            new ProgLang() { lang = "java", Checked = true},
            new ProgLang() { lang = "python", Checked = false},
            new ProgLang() { lang = "php", Checked = true},
        };

        return View(obj);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(UserReg obj)
    {
        return View(obj);
    }
```

Кусок представления:

```
     <div>
        Programming languages
        <div class="prog-lang-holder">
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ProgLangList.Count; i++)
            {
                var ProgLang = Model.ProgLangList[i];
                <label>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.ProgLangList[i].lang)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.ProgLangList[i].lang)
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.ProgLangList[i].Checked)
                </label>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
```

В модели UserReg есть свойство List ProgLangList, значение которого я никак не могу получить в контроллере.
Мега-плиз, подскажите что делаю не так.